# Write long statement in multiple lines

Tags: go

I have a quite long `func` declaration that I would like to split into several lines:

```
func LongMethodName(param1 *Type1, param2 *Type2, param3 *Type3) (param4 *Type1, param5 *Type2, param6 *Type3) {
    ...
    return
}
```

it is quite unmanageable.

Is there a way of writing a function declaration as follows?

```
func LongMethodName(param1 *Type1, param2 *Type2, param3 *Type3)
    (param4 *Type1, param5 *Type2, param6 *Type3)
{
    ...
    return
}
```

Comment: Use `go fmt` and never think about formatting again. What you can do it tweak your editor to intelligently wrap long lines, refactor your code or just live with it…

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a result of the semicolon insertion rule: http://golang.org/ref/spec#Semicolons. Go automatically inserts a semicolon right at the end of the first line:

```
func LongMethodName(param1 *Type1, param2 *Type2, param3 *Type3);
    (param4 *Type1, param5 *Type2, param6 *Type3) {
```

The first line with the semicolon is actually a valid go expression: **It's an external function**. Then, it tries to parse the second line and fails!

You can wrap it either by keeping the opening parenthesis on the first line:

```
func LongMethodName(param1 *Type1, param2 *Type2, param3 *Type3) (
    param4 *Type1, param5 *Type2, param6 *Type3) {
}
```

or by keeping a comma on the first line:

```
func LongMethodName(param1 *Type1, param2 *Type2,
    param3 *Type3) (param4 *Type1, param5 *Type2, param6 *Type3) {
}
```

Both are valid in `gofmt`.